# Loopback: use isValid() in update

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

At some point in my app, I want to validate request data before updating an existing instance, so I am using [isValid()](https://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-prototype-isvalid) method. But it fails validation due to uniqueness of an attribute.

```js
const userInfo = {
  id: data.id,
  name: data.name,
  email: data.email,
  password: data.password
};
const instance = new app.models.User(userInfo);
instance.isValid(valid => {
  console.log(valid); //false, "email" is not unique and "id" should be absent
});
```

How could I set that I am validating in update not in create.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback thinks that your user is a new model instance. As the result, validation fails (a new instance shouldn't have id and "another" user with this emails exists in your database).

Use persisted options to tell loopback that your user has been saved in the database earlier:

```
new app.models.User(userInfo, {persisted: true})
```

Almost the same approach loopback uses in his Modle.find() method to convert data from database to a loopback model instance:

```
var ctorOpts = {
  fields: query.fields,
  applySetters: false,
  persisted: true,
};

var obj;
try {
  obj = new Model(data, ctorOpts);
} catch (err) {
  return callback(err);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote almost your example to check. Are the errors the same?